# Android Beacon sample app

Tags: android, android-logcat, ibeacon-android

I trying to build a app on beacons. so I got a sample code from [here.](https://github.com/hugohabel/MyBeaconsDemo)

I have run that code and as soon as I entered into range of beacon the app is crashed and error in the logcat is as follow:

```
06-20 17:48:24.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18104): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Please help me out.

I checked the code and the error lies in between these lines.

```
iBeaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<IBeacon> iBeacons, Region region) {
            if (iBeacons.size() > 0) {
                double distance = iBeacons.iterator().next().getAccuracy();
                DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
                double distanceFormatted = Double.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(distance));
                TextView distanceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.am_tv_distance);
                distanceTextView.setText(String.valueOf(distanceFormatted) + " m");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform UI changes in the UI thread:

```
    iBeaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
    @Override
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<IBeacon> iBeacons, Region region) {
        if (iBeacons.size() > 0) {
            double distance = iBeacons.iterator().next().getAccuracy();
            DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
            double distanceFormatted = Double.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(distance));
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                        TextView distanceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.am_tv_distance);
                        distanceTextView.setText(String.valueOf(distanceFormatted) + " m");
                  }
            });
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I am getting only distance not range

Comment: whatever you are doing, when you modify the ui, you need to do it in the UI thread.

So, you need to change these lines:
TextView distanceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.am_tv_distance);
distanceTextView.setText(String.valueOf(distanceFormatted) + " m");
                 
with these:

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                        TextView distanceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.am_tv_distance);distanceTextView.setText(String.valueOf(distanceFormatted) + " m");
                  }
            });

Comment: This is correct.  You must wrap any UI changes in a library callback method in runOnUIThread.

Answer (score 0):

For the `CalledFromWrongThreadException`,

write a function and call that like:

```
private void toastToDisplay(final String line) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "" + line,
                    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            TextView yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_tv);
            yourTextView .setText(line);
        }
    });
}
```

You can edit that function with your required `distanceTextView` or other views if you want. 
What happens there is that the Service is running on the background thread in your application, so when you directly call an operation that would update the UI, it conflicts with the thread you are in while writing that code.

So If the current thread is not the UI thread, the action is posted to the event queue of the UI thread by using [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

What exactly is the meaning of "I am getting only distance not range" ?
...for the `iBeacons.iterator().next().getAccuracy();`, part.. you can collect the beacon details by using a for each loop like:

```
for (IBeacon iBeacon : iBeacons) {
String line = "Major: " + iBeacon.getMajor()
                                    + "Minor: " + iBeacon.getMinor()
                                    + "Accuracy in m(s): "
                                    + iBeacon.getAccuracy()
                                    + "BluetoothAddress: "
                                    + iBeacon.getBluetoothAddress()
                                    + "Proximity: " + iBeacon.getProximity()
                                    + "ProximityUuid: "
                                    + iBeacon.getProximityUuid() + "Rssi: "
                                    + iBeacon.getRssi() + "TxPower: "
                                    + iBeacon.getTxPower(); 
toastToDisplay(line);
    }
```

In case you haven't already seen it, [this Android iBeacon Library sample application](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/samples.html) is a good reference.